# How to select rows that have numbers as a value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got a table with a column that is type of VARCHAR2(255 BYTE). I would like to select only these rows that have numbers as a value, so I discard any other values as for example "lala","1z".  I just want to have pure numbers from 1 to ..... 999999999 (just digital numbers in other words) :P

Could you tell me how to make it?

Comment: Hi maksi111, what sql plateform are you using?

Comment: @zip oracle sql developer

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/IS_NUMBER

Answer (score 2):

if you're using Oracle 12c r2 or later then use the built-in `validate_conversion()` function:

```
select *
from your_table
where validate_conversion(cast(your_column as number)) = 0
```

`validate_conversion()` returns `0` when the proposed conversion would succeed and `1` when it wouldn't. It also supports date and timestamp conversions. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is the usual option. You could use regexp, but it's usually a bit slower.

```
select column1 
from tableA
where translate(column1, '1234567890', '') is null;
```

Comment: it has worked with trim(TRANSLATE(..., '0123456789-,.', ' ')) is null;

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regexp version kfinity referred to.  The regex matches a line consisting of 1 or more digits.

```
select column1 
from tableA
where regexp_like(column1, '^\d+$');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want zero to start a number.  So it seems like regular expressions are the way to go:

```
where regexp_like(column1, '^[1-9][0-9]*$');
```